# jQuery not finding value in textarea

Tags: javascript

I am creating a forum but when you post a reply, jQuery keeps displaying the error that the textarea is empty when it's not.

```
if (post_body.val() == "") {
    $("#formError").html('<font size="+2">Please type something</font>').show().fadeOut(3000);
}
```

[Here's all the code on the page](http://jsfiddle.net/3ymckbuj/2/)

Comment: This is too messy a code for us to help, we are not going to go through all of your code. Please provide a jsfiddle with the necessary code, so we can go through it.

Comment: Please put your code here with a bit more detail on the EXACT line you are challenged with, we are NOT going to look at a page/link raw in most cases and questions on code with no code will likely get closed\down voted as I see has occured,

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with the javascript and html in question http://jsfiddle.net/3ymckbuj/

Comment: It is line 21 in the javascript that seems to be causing an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple tags with the attribute `id="post_body"`.
An id needs to be unique, so remove it from all elements but your textarea.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that. Guess I should look at my code more closely